# Missing number treated as zero using booktabs+siunits

Tags: multicolumn

I am learning to use the `siunits` package in a tabular environment to align number by their decimal point.

I was watching the top answer given in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303395/align-numbers-based-on-their-decimal-point?noredirect=1&lq=1) question by Bernard and when I tried to implement its code into my table but I get a `missing number treated as zero`.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   c
l.15    \multicolumn{c}{1}{$\theta$ ($^{\circ}$)}
                                                & \multicolumn{c}{1}{$\sigma...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

this is my MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{ l*{5}{S[table-format=4.2, table-number-alignment=center]}}
    \toprule 
    \multicolumn{c}{1}{$\theta$ ($^{\circ}$)} & \multicolumn{c}{1}{$\sigma_x^' $ (kips)} & \multicolumn{c}{1}{$\sigma_y^'$ (kips)} & \multicolumn{c}{1}{$\tau_{xy}^'$ (kips)} & \multicolumn{c}{1}{$2\theta_p$ ($^{\circ}$)}\\\midrule
    0 & 10 & 0 & 6 & 50.1944\\
    15 & 12.3301 & -2.3301 & 2.6962 & 20.1944\\
    30 & 12.6962 & -2.6962 & -1.3301 & 350.1944\\
    45 & 11 & -1 & -5 & 320.1944\\
    60 & 7.6962 & 2.3038 & -7.3301 & 290.1944\\
    75 & 3.6699 & 6.3301 & -7.6962 & 260.1944\\
    90 & 0 & 10 & -6 & 230.1944\\
    105 & -2.3301 & 12.3301 & -2.6962 & 200.1944\\
    120 & -2.6962 & 12.6962 & 1.3301 & 170.1944\\
    135 & -1 & 11 & 5 & 140.1944\\
    150 & 2.3038 & 7.6962 & 7.3301 & 110.1944\\
    165 & 6.3301 & 3.6699 & 7.6962 & 80.1944\\
    180 & 10 & 0 & 6 & 50.1944\\
    \bottomrule \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you post a minimal example? The first compile run gave me an error message highlighting `\multicolumn{c}{1}{$\theta$ ($^{\circ}$)}` The syntax is wrong. First the number of columns, then the alignment. It should be `\multicolumn{1}{c}{content}`.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make any sense to have just one column for a multicol. You are probably looking for `{content}`.

Comment: You should learn how to use a package by reading the documentation. `4.2` is wrong for *all* your columns. Only a documentation can clearly and up to date explain what the parameters mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Johannnes_B said in his comments, the correct syntax of `\multicolumn` command is

```
\multicolumn{cols}{pos}{text}
```

where cols=number of columns, pos=alignment, and text=content. but is your case it is enough to put the content within `{ }`.

`table-format=4.2` means 4 integers and 2 decimals, I changed it according to the content of the various columns.

I would like to add that in your column definition you have 6 columns (one `l` and five `S`), whereas your table only has 5 columns.

Moreover `$\sigma_x^'$` is not correct, the `'` should be put within `{ }`, but I think you simply need `$\sigma_x'$`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tabular}{
            S[table-format = 3]
            *2{S[table-format = -2.4]}
            S[table-format = -1.4]
            S[table-format = 3.4]
        }
        \toprule 
        {$\theta$ ($^{\circ}$)} &
        {$\sigma_x'$ (kips)} &
        {$\sigma_y'$ (kips)} & 
        {$\tau_{xy}'$ (kips)} & 
        {$2\theta_p$ ($^{\circ}$)}\\
        \midrule
        0 & 10 & 0 & 6 & 50.1944\\
        15 & 12.3301 & -2.3301 & 2.6962 & 20.1944\\
        30 & 12.6962 & -2.6962 & -1.3301 & 350.1944\\
        45 & 11 & -1 & -5 & 320.1944\\
        60 & 7.6962 & 2.3038 & -7.3301 & 290.1944\\
        75 & 3.6699 & 6.3301 & -7.6962 & 260.1944\\
        90 & 0 & 10 & -6 & 230.1944\\
        105 & -2.3301 & 12.3301 & -2.6962 & 200.1944\\
        120 & -2.6962 & 12.6962 & 1.3301 & 170.1944\\
        135 & -1 & 11 & 5 & 140.1944\\
        150 & 2.3038 & 7.6962 & 7.3301 & 110.1944\\
        165 & 6.3301 & 3.6699 & 7.6962 & 80.1944\\
        180 & 10 & 0 & 6 & 50.1944\\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PaulLara You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!